# How to map JSON to POJO with dynamic property name using JsInterop

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I have this kind of JSON that needs to be converted to POJO using JsInterop:

```
            "ACL": {
                "*": {
                    "read": true
                },
                "asdf123asdf": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                }
            }
```

Where the `asdf123asdf` can be any property name. Here's one I have some up (partially)

```
@JsType(isNative = true, namespace= JsPackage.GLOBAL, name="Object")
public class ACL {
    @JsProperty(name="*")
    String asterisk;
}
```

Is there a work around to implment the dynamic property name?

Comment: One option would be to entirely / dynamically generate your POJO based on the JSON content (annotations included), by using a code generation and manipulation library (e.g. Byte Buddy - http://bytebuddy.net/  -  the most acclaimed nowadays). You could either generate Java code or directly bytecode, in a build step prior to regular compilation and you could also package your POJOs as a separate project module. That would be the type-safe option...

Comment: You would probably need to take into account JSON property names that are not valid Java identifiers. Or, you could use a Map, right? That would be the second, type-unsafe option...

Comment: @OctavianTheodor I don't think ByteBuddy can even work with GWT

Comment: I was actually thinking of generating the necessary POJOs not at runtime but in a build step, before actually compiling your app, which, in turn, depends on GWT. The generation part / code need not be included in the final application. It's true that this means to already know how the most comprehensive JSON will look like...